# Is $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ (a set of all rational sequences) a homogeneous space?

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers, homogeneous-spaces

Is $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ a homogeneous space?

This space is defined as a set of all rational sequences, also sometimes denoted $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. It is the set of all functions from the naturals to the rationals. I assume the standard product topology on $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$

I am asking about homogeneity of this space, since it would mean there is a "rich" group of automorphisms here. Which would tell that a lot of points are "topologically the same".

My guess would be that $\mathbb{Q}^\omega$ **is** homogeneous, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is homogeneous too, but I dont have any idea how to prove it.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Any product of homogeneous spaces is homogeneous.

Comment: Given any two elements $a,b \in \mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}$, write down explicitly a homeomorphism taking $a$ to $b$.  Use a translation in $\mathbb Q$ for each factor, and use the definition of "product topology".